# ruby (1.8.7): How to get rid of non-printable chars while scraping?

Tags: ruby, utf-8, nokogiri

I'm trying to parse an HTML page with Nokogiri but I'm having some issues with text. Mainly, I cannot get rid of unwanted chars. While parsing, when I obtain a String I always try to clean it as much as possible. I try to convert nonprintable chars to unique spaces. I use this method without success after a lot of modifications:

```
def clear_string(str)
  CGI::unescapeHTML(str).gsub(/\s+/mu," ").strip
end
```

For instance, supose this HTML fragment (copy-pasted from http://www.gisa.cat/gisa/servlet/HomeLicitation?licitationID=1061525)

```
<tr>
    <td><span class="linkred2">Tramitaci&oacute;:</span></td>
    <td>&nbsp;ordinària </td>
</tr>
```

Some intermediate example outputs showed by Netbeans 7.0 using Nokogiri and `clear_string` (the method defined above)

```
row.at("td[1]").text # => "Tramitació:"
row.at("td[2]").text # => " ordinària "
clear_string(row.at("td[2]").text) # => " ordinària"
row.at("td[2]").text.scan(/./mu) # => ["\302\240", "o", "r", "d", "i", "n", "\303\240", "r", "i", "a", " "]
```

I don't know why `strip` doesn't get rid of first spaces. Moreover, the parsing result after applying `clear_string`, is dumped into a yaml file using `YAML::dump`. Its contents are respectively, for both texts:

```
"Tramitaci\xC3\xB3:"
!binary |
  wqBvcmRpbsOgcmlh
```

The first one seems barely OK, but I don't know how to fix the second case.

Comment: Which version of Nokogiri are you using?

Comment: mechanize 1.0.0 and nokogiri 1.4.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to translate characters from one character set to another is to use `Iconv`. For example if what you are looking for is just converting UTF8 to ASCII you could do something like this:

```
require 'iconv'

s = "ordinària"
Iconv.conv('ASCII//TRANSLIT', 'UTF8', s)
=> "ordinaria"
```

The `TRANSLIT` switch tells `Iconv` to try and transliterate (approximately match) unconvertable characters. If you instead want to completely ignore unconvertable characters then you can use the `IGNORE` switch:

```
Iconv.conv('ASCII//IGNORE', 'UTF8', s)
=> "ordinria"
```

Note that `Iconv` will throw an exception with `TRANSLIT` if it finds something it can't convert. For that you can combine `IGNORE` and `TRANSLIT` like so:

```
Iconv.conv('ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', 'UTF8', s)
=> "ordinaria"
```